# Load Python Script: Python engine session was not found - Uipath

Tags: python, uipath

Can you help me with this error? Python is installed in c drive and referenced in python scope activity.
Error-

RemoteException wrapping System.InvalidOperationException: Python engine session was not found
at UiPath.Python.Activities.PythonScope.GetPythonEngine(ActivityContext context)
at UiPath.Python.Activities.LoadScript.d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at UiPath.Shared.Activities.AsyncTaskCodeActivity.EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context,
IAsyncResult result)
at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.System.Activities.IAsyncCodeActivity.FinishExecution(AsyncCodeActivityContext context,
IAsyncResult result)
at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor,
BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you can show the workflow in operation and confirm the details of where your script is to be loaded from, it will help in diagnosing any issues